# Hard drive does not fit correctly, what to do?

Tags: hard-drive, case

I have recieved an old computer minus the hard drive. I had a hard drive lying around to put into it. However, when the previous owner removed their hard drive, they also took the clips required to insert the hard drive. Today, I got around to installing my hard drive, and noticed this. When I asked the previous owner, they said they threw out the clips.

The drive bay is significantly larger than the  hard drive, so just sliding the drive in leaves it too loose to use. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get creative, a good old piece of cardboard will prevent the hard drive from shifting around. :)

maybe you can fix it on one side with screws.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a CD style bay you're trying to fit it into then you can get [conversion kits](http://www.maplin.co.uk/Module.aspx?ModuleNo=36414&C=SO&U=strat15) for 5.25" to 3.5".

Failing that, you're going to have to improvise. Something to absorb the vibration (cardboad works fine), and either screws or good strong duct tape. Depending on the case and your experience, you can sometimes drill holes or attach a custom made bracket to hold the drive.

Comment: It's not a CD bay. It is the actual hard drive bay. It's probably about 4". This computer originally came with clips that you screwed on the drive to make it fit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to check either a computer builder near you that has been in business long enough to have old parts lying around, or get online and start searching. Here is a pair of metal rails I found by googling hard drive mounting rails, http://www.directron.com/cdrail.html.

Answer (score 0):

Well, improvise, or see if you can order the bits from the maker. I know Antec sells the trays and vibration absorbing screw kits for mounting drives (and has really nice customer service people!).